# How can create dynamic UIButton from items of database?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm building an app with swift 3.0 using Xcode.

So, I have build this screen:
[image]

Now under the write (22.05...) I want to insert any custom Button or custom View like this:

[image]

But the number of it is not fixed depends of the number of items storage in database. It could be also 100, so I should to put in the screen all button.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Have a look at the Firebase real-time database. Plenty of tutorials everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `UIStackView`, and insert a button into it for every entry in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is set vertical `UIStackView` inside simple `UIView`. Add image in top section of stack and label in bottom section of stack. Last action - add button without label and background color above stack.

Approximate tree-like view:

```
    - Root View
    -- UIView(Container)
    --- UIStackView
    ---- UIImageView
    ---- UILabel
    --- UIButton
```

Best way create simple control, but it's up to u.
if you want to create button based on response, i think, best way if `CollectionView` usage where cell is your button.

In this way you have scrollable and no so difficulty customized space for your buttons